# Detecting CNAME in url of incoming trafic

Tags: php, dns, cname

I'm trying to detect the CNAME used on incoming traffic so I can customize a site accordingly.  I have a site that displays some info to the client (actually more complicated, but will work for an example). Some of my customers send their own customers to my site to see this info. They are using a CNAME to get to my site. I would like to display certain logos etc to the viewer based on what CNAME was used to get to my page.

What I have come up with so far is using dns_get_record, I'm I on the right track with that if it can be done at all?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question is not clear. There's no need to "detect the CNAME" because you will get this directly from the request. For example, if abc.example.com is the CNAME for www.example.com, and if the user goes to abc.example.com, this is what you will see in the HTTP request (you won't see www.example.com).

Comment: So would all I need is $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']? I've heard that this doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: _$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']_ contains the content of the _Host_ request header, which is sent by the browser, however, the _Host_ header is not strictly required. It's used by the web server to determine which virtual host should be used to process the request in the case of many domains being accessed via 1 IP. All major browsers supply the _Host_ header correctly, so if your users are using regular browsers, it shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language that your web content is written in, it also depends on what webserver you are using. What you want to look for in the web content is the "HOST header". If you want to treat it differently at the web server then what you want to look for is "virtual hosts".